# How to Generate a Word Document from a Form of Input Fields? A real template?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a contract that is pretty long. 18 pages in small print. Every once in a while I need to produce this contract with different "Variables". One time it can be between company ACME and John Doe, another time between company ACME2 and Jane Doe.

I was hoping that I could use the same dummy code, but force word to pop up a form, that requires me to enter some values for the variables, I want to define.

That way I wouldn't need to change the document by hand every time.

Initially I wanted to create the document by building a custom web application for it, but I am not sure that I could manage the formatting the way it looks right now. Let alone the time investment for it.

## Question

Is it possible to do with work or do I have to make a custom solution for this? Can't imagine that such a powerful tool like Microsoft Word, that is out there for decades, doesn't have that kind of feature, since I can think of a lot of applications for it, f.e. invoicing, simple letters

Kind regards,

George

Comment: Pretty sure this is possible with Mail Merge. I've never used the feature fully though.

Comment: After playing with Mail Merge, I think this is exactly what you need.

Comment: In general, I agree about Mail Merge, esp. if you'll need to generate several of these docs at the same time. On the other hand, if you'll generate just one at a time, you might also want to check out, e.g., my answer to [Looking for an alternative for MS WORD Mail Merge](https://superuser.com/questions/1187261/looking-for-an-alternative-for-ms-word-mail-merge), which explains how you can use ASK and REF fields so that Word present a series of dialog boxes that prompt for the variable information up front and then propagates that information throughout the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Mail Merge feature to do exactly this. It allows you to substitute things like Names, Companies, and Addresses with placeholders that will automatically be inserted when you complete the document.

Here is a before and after of using Mail Merge to achieve a default template for a letter:
[image: Before Mail Merge]

[image: After Mail Merge]

The Mail Merge Wizard is extremely simple to use, but if you need a thorough tutorial, please comment and I'll put together a series of screenshots.

Comment: I have to admit, it's not the feature that I thought I would use, but it surely get's the work done.

Yet I probably program it myself. Thanks anyway.